# codenameone XML from device

Tags: xml, codenameone

How would I go about reading XML from a file on the device?
Can you add the XML to a .res file? I know the XML parser expects a reader, but can you use a reader to read out the .res file?

Regards,

Dylan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you absolutely can. Open the *theme.res* file with the *Codename One Designer* and add your xml file from the Data section on the left. Now you can load the file using the `theme` object as follows:

```
InputStream is = theme.getData("yourFile.xml");
```

Alternatively, You can put your xml in the class path (e.g. java source directory) and load it as follows:

```
InputStream is = Display.getInstance().getResourceAsStream(null, "/yourFile.xml");
```

Once you got an `InputStream`, simply wrap it with a `Reader`

```
XMLParser xmlParser = new XMLParser();
xmlParser.parse(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"));
```

Comment: Great answer, I would use new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8") since the default is to use the platform specific encoding and that can be just about anything.

Comment: Thanks @ShaiAlmog. updated my answer -and actually my own application's code :)- accordingly